# selecting null and notnull values on same query

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I'm trying to pull a list of records in Crystal that will allow for any value as well as blank values. I have tried to use the following code:

```
isnull({DELAY_CODE}) or not(isnull({DELAY_CODE}))
```

and the report still ignores the null values. If I only use the `isnull` portion of the code, I get only the records that have blank values in the `DELAY_CODE` field.

Essentially, I want to be able to use the select expert `"is any value"` option and also grab the records that have no value.

Comment: Your snippet of code doesn't do anything since it will _always_ evaluate to true (a field is either null or it isn't), which functionally does not affect the report in any way. Now, maybe you mean to check for null values as well as empty strings, aka a "blank"?

Comment: Show us your your data which you "selected" and how does your report look like after that data is processed

Comment: Perhaps I do mean "blank" values.  Here's my issue. This is my selection criteria:
{JOB_MAIN.WORK_ORDER_STATUS} = "OPEN" and
{JOB_MAIN.REAS_REAS_FOR_REPAIR} = "S" and
{JOB_MAIN.JOB_TYPE} = "PM"
However, there is a display field capturing the Delay status of the job. If this status has no value, the record will not pull into the report. I am trying to set it so it selects records based on the above criteria, regardless of the delay status.

Comment: So the report is ignoring your blank records, hmm..  Get rid of that selection criteria then:  File > options > Reporting tab > select or unselect 'convert database null values to default' and see if changes things.. and depending on the data displayed look at database > uncheck 'select district records'.